# Не работает выборка из бд по дате

Tags: php, sql, дата

Доброго времени! Знаю есть много похожих вопросов тут, я их просмотрел но подходящего варианта не нашел - попробовал просто не сработало. В комментариях к нексольким вопросам задавал вопрос но тоже не получилось разобраться - по сему ногами не бейте) суть такова

```
$datenow = date("Y-m-d");
    $tmpact = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM actions WHERE fdate <= '$datenow' AND tohda <= '$datenow'");
```

при том поля fdate и tohda содержат в базе строки с такими датами:

fdate - 2016-11-12 и 2016-09-02
и
tohda - 2017-08-14 и 2018-08-01 соответственно

но запрос возвращает 0 строк, при том если я убираю полностью условия WHERE просто делаю выборку то все выбирается запрос проходит, поля в BD в котрые записаны даты (fdate и tohda) имеют тип данных DATE. Так же пробовал STR_TO_DATE - так же эфекта нету. Помогите пожалуйста возможно я просто не вижу очевидных вещей каких то
        и даже вот так не работает когда на прямую

$tmpact = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM actions WHERE fdate <= '2016-04-01' AND tohda <= '2016-04-01'");

Comment: Постарайся все-таки разглядеть, какая дата у тебя на самом деле в БД.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учимся отлаживать SQL.
Для начала пишем так

```
$datenow = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM actions WHERE fdate <= '$datenow' AND tohda <= '$datenow'";
die($sql);
```

И смотрим на полученный запрос, все ли с ним нормально. Если да, то идем в консоль mysql (или, прости господи, похапемайадмин) и запускаем запрос там.

Если там находит строки, то проверяем, к какой БД подключаемся в РНР.
Если не находит, то проверяем свои фантазии о том, какие данные на самом деле записаны в БД, например так:

```
SELECT fdate, '$datenow', fdate <= '$datenow' as result FROM actions
```

и смотрим, что выведет.

Отдельно следует отметить, что вместо богомерзкой mysql_query и запихивания переменных прямо в запрос следует использовать PDO и плейсхолдеры.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM actions WHERE fdate <= ? AND tohda <= ?");
$stmt->execute([$datenow,$datenow]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: `$stmt->execute([$datenow, $datenow]);` ?

Comment: @Ипатьев блин даже запроссом на прямую без переменных так SELECT fdate, '2016-08-08', fdate <= '2016-08-08' AS result
FROM hystactionsda ноль строк выдает!(

Comment: @dantelol Надо выполнить запрос, который я привел выше- запрос, который показывает рядом дату, значение из поля и результат сравнения. Хотя и так ясно, что проблема в данных в БД

Comment: @Ипатьев к слову вот скрины полей в БД [Поля в бд]()

Comment: @Ипатьев [скрин запроса](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=b9c98e5a1673e5aeafc9a6b6408d1da7) вот так вернул запрос = ПМА юзаю - так как сайт делаю\

Comment: Информация на скрине не соответствует данным приведенным в вопросе.

Comment: @dantelol ДАТА там другая в базе прописана. Не та, которую ты в своем вопросе написал. Короче. Если ты не можешь понять, глядя на две даты, какая из них больше, то тебе пока рановато заниматься программированием. Попробуй подтянуть арифметику.

Comment: @Ипатьев а да да да вы правы не доглядел теперь все работатет сделал как у вас все) спасибо) глаза просто уже замылились вчера все перезагружал в базе ошибся